# Merging two linked Json data using Angular

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to merge two JSON data .
example : 
**json 1 :**

```
{
      "countryCode":"AD",
      "countryName":"Andorra",
      "currencyCode":"EUR"
   },
   {
      "countryCode":"AE",
      "countryName":"United Arab Emirates",
      "currencyCode":"AED"
   }
```

**json 2 :**

```
{
      "code":"AED",
      "name":"Arab Emirates Dirham",
      "locale":"ar_AE",
      "display":1
   },
   {
      "code":"AFN",
      "name":"Afghanistan Afghani",
      "locale":"ps_AF",
      "display":1
   }
```

I want to merge this two json object based on the data .

Comment: I want to display country name  and corresponding currency value using the currency code .

Answer (score 0):

Use [angular.extend](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.extend) function:

```
angular.extend(json1, json2);
```